# Access Corda Network Map Identity (Corda 2.0)

Tags: corda

I want to access the identity of the network map node (without knowing his name). How I can do this ?
Is it possible to access node.conf data in cordapps (so I can find network map identity) ?

My final goal is to remove network map node from the list of peers.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the node's `node.conf` file from within a flow as follows:

```
@Suspendable
@Override
public Void call() {
    try (FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("./node.conf")) {
        String confContents = IOUtils.toString(inputStream);
        getLogger().info(confContents);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

The working directory when running a flow is the node's base directory, where the `node.conf` file is stored. When running flow tests, this flow will not work, as the base directory is different.

A future version of Corda will introduce per-CorDapp configuration files that can easily be accessed during flows.